# g++ can't seem to infer datatype unless declared on a separate line (unlike Visual C++)?

Tags: c++, g++

I run into some issues because I develop with Visual C++ on Windows, and then also compile on Linux using g++.  One thing I ran into that I don't understand is that g++ doesn't seem to be able match data types passed to a function if you pass a reference to the constructor to the function.  Specifically, given a method signature like this:

```
static int to_int(string& value);
```

If it is called like this:

```
int id_number = EZXMsg::to_int(string(tokens[index]));
```

(Where tokens type is a `vector<char*>& tokens`)

g++ gives the error:

> main.cpp:130: error: no matching function for call to
>   'ezx::iserver::EZXMsg::to_int(std::string)'
>   ../iserver-api/ezxmsg.h:50: note: candidates are: static int
>   ezx::iserver::EZXMsg::to_int(std::string&)

Visual C++ doesn't have problem compiling this though.  To fix it for g++, the code needs to be like this:

```
string value(tokens[index]);
int roid = EZXMsg::to_int(value);
```

What is the reason for g++ needing that additional line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference. That is not allowed in standard C++.

```
static int to_int(string& value);
//                ^^^^^^^ non-const reference

int id_number = EZXMsg::to_int(string(tokens[index]));
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary string: no no!
```

The most likely solution is to pass a `const` reference:

```
static int to_int(const string& value);
//                ^^^^^ const reference: yes yes!
```

If you really need to mutate the string inside of the function (which a `to_int` function is unlikely to need), you would have to pass a non-temporary string to a function taking a non-const reference:

```
auto s = string(tokens[index]);
int id_number = EZXMsg::to_int(s); // OK, s is not a temporary
```

Comment: so you're trying to say Microsoft is not standard?  :)

Comment: @SamGoldberg, yes. The extensions can be disabled via a compiler switch (see [Disable Language Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: I'll give your change a try. It makes sense to me now that you've explained it.  Good clear explanation (especially for a beginner like me)!

Comment: @SamGoldberg this is one of the (in)famous MS extensions. Fortunately I am sheltered from all of that so I've never been bitten by this.